# Upload assets to Site.com via FTP or REST API?

Tags: api, rest, site.com, upload

I am using site.com to host a mini site which works fine. I need another delivery method other than manually uploading my .zip file to my site as an asset.

I have found a way to expose an endpoint referencing this fairly old document: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/02/quick-tip-public-restful-web-services-on-force-com-sites.html.

I successfully created a small program to retrieve and send back information when hitting the endpoint from the CLI:

```
    @RestResource(urlMapping='/myservice')
global class MyService {
    @HttpGet
    global static String doGet() {

        // the site name provided
        String name = RestContext.request.params.get('name');

        // get the site information
        Site site = [SELECT Name FROM Site WHERE Name =: name Limit 1];
        String label = [SELECT MasterLabel FROM Site where Name =: site.Name].MasterLabel;
        Id admin = [SELECT AdminId FROM Site where name =: site.Name].AdminId;

        // get the site admin information
        User contact = [SELECT id FROM User where id =: admin Limit 1];
        String contactFirstName = [SELECT FirstName FROM User where id =: contact.Id].FirstName;
        String contactLastName = [SELECT LastName FROM User where id =: contact.Id].LastName;


        return 'The contact for the '+label+' site is '+contactFirstName+' '+contactLastName;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to extend this type of service to accept uploading a document?

Comment: I think you are going to want an `@HttpPost` method....

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example code of how to do it to accept binary data

```
@HttpPost
global static String insertContentVersion(RestRequest req) {
      ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion(
                // data fields
                versionData = req.requestBody,
                title = 'Test',
                description = 'Description',
            );
  insert cv;
  return cv.Id
}
```

The req.requestBody is the base64 ecode of the binary data you want in the request body .

You can change the code to accept document object as well along same lines

Note that this will have a limit of 3MB because of apex limits .